# Displaying PHP/MySQLi results as HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

I click an HTML button to run a JS script which posts date criteria (entered elsewhere on the page) to a PHP page which then queries a MySQLi database. I want to display the results in an auto-generated HTML table and I want that table to be in a specific div on the page. My HTML code is:

```
<div id="buttonContainer">
    <input type="button" id="reportButton" value="Generate Report" onclick="generateReport();">
</div>  
<div id="displayTable">
</div>
```

My JS code is:

```
window.generateReport = function(){    
    $.post("PhotoTopTen.php", {
        startdate: startDate,
        enddate: endDate,
    });
}
```

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
$startdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST["startdate"]));
$enddate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST["enddate"]));
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","User","password","dbase");
$sql="SELECT Document, COUNT(*) as count FROM table WHERE event LIKE 'Photo%' GROUP BY Document ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
};
$colNames = array_keys(reset($data))
echo "<table><tr>";
foreach($colNames as $colName) {
    echo "<th>$colName</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($colNames as $colName) {
        echo "<td>".$row[$colName]."</td>";
    }   
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

?>

I know the MySQLi query works because I've tested it in phpMyAdmin. I also know that my mistake is to echo back HTML tags to the JS file (instead of to the HMTL page) but I just don't know how to do it any other way. I've tried echoing the HTML back within JS script tags but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Try this: `window.generateReport = function(){    
    $.post("PhotoTopTen.php", {
        startdate: startDate,
        enddate: endDate,
    }, function(data){ $('#displayTable').html(data); });
}`

Comment: Thanks - that helps. I can see how this makes the link from PHP to JS to HTML. However my PHP script is getting stuck at the `$colNames = array_keys(reset($data))` line and I get a 500 Internal Server Error in my Chrome console.

Comment: What does it return ?

Comment: Oh.. I fixed it. Just a simple ; missing. Thanks for the steer on the `function(data){ $('#displayTable').html(data); }`

Comment: _Human error!_ Always use IDE to avoid such errors..

Comment: How do I tick the question answered box. There doesn't seem to be a checkmark to tick but I've clicked the star icon.

Comment: What you want to do ? You have already accepted the answer provided below..

Comment: Well.. I wanted to explicitly accept your answer as well as the one below. Both answers are similar but you've provided me with some extra help. Does the forum only allow me to tick one answer?

Comment: Mine is a comment, not an answer :P You can upvote many answers but can accept only one as correct answer not many :)

Comment: Got it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to show the result in the div. Try as below :

```
$.post("PhotoTopTen.php", {startdate: startDate,enddate: endDate}, function( data ) {
     $( "#displayTable" ).html( data );
});
```